# How to check Port 1433 is working for Sql Server or not?

Tags: sql-server

How can I check whether port 1433 is open for Sql Server or not? I have set in bound and out bound rules, checked in SQL config manager but not sure whether it is working.

Comment: This will Help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23704/easy-way-to-check-connectivity-to-sql-server-from-client

Answer (score 22):

If TELNET is installed, you could use `TELNET 1433` to verify port connectivity.  Otherwise, the PowerShell command below can do the job using a .NET `TcpClient`:

```
$server="yourserver"; $port=1433; echo ((new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient).Connect($server,$port)) "$server is listening on TCP port $port";
```

Newer versions of PowerShell include a `Test-NetConnection` cmdlet (alias `tnc`) to facilitate testing ICMP and port connectivity. Example invocations from a Windows command prompt:

```
powershell -Command "Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 'yourserver' -Port 1433"
powershell -Command "tnc -ComputerName 'yourserver' -Port 1433"
powershell -Command "tnc 'yourserver' -Port 1433"
```

Answer (score 10):

You probaly want it open, since You are asking. The single most time-saving image I have found for this is here:

This is an inferred answer to the question, somewhat meta, but in my opinion the one that counts.

[image: computer administration win 10]

Comment: This configuration was missing for me on a standard install of SQL server 2019, the TCP Port for IPAll was empty.  after i set it to 1433 everything worked, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If the server is using TCP/IP, then the simple way is to just telnet to the SQL Server port and see if it connects. By default, that's port 1433, so this should work:

```
telnet servername 1433
```

That will probably be appropriate in most cases.

If it's using a different port, or dynamic ports (common with a named instance), then you'll need to determine which port it's currently listening on. Check SQL Server configuration manager to see if it's a specific port, or dynamic ports. If it's using dynamic ports, then as long as you don't have multiple instances on the server, `netstat -abn`is probably the simplest way to find what it's using. Otherwise, dig through the Windows event log or the SQL Server error log for a message indicating which port is in use by the instance.

If SQL Server is using Named Pipes, then I believe if you're able to access shares on the machine, you have adequate network connectivity. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275787%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) says you can go further and try connecting to the IPC$ share:

```
 net use \\servername\IPC$
```

That's written for SQL Server 2000, but I don't imagine this aspect has changed much, if at all.

Comment: @Neeraj I got Failed to open loopback connection error

Comment: @Sprezlaus yes it is simply what i want

Comment: I am having cmd error for telnet myservername 1433. I can't telnet. why?

Comment: @LittleBirdy, if you have verified the SQL Server service is running and see the port 1433 listening message in the SQL Server error log, it must be network connectivity.  Besides the Windows firewall, there may be another firewall in the way.

Comment: @Dan Guzman, I can't telnet because i haven't install it. Interesting...what could possibly blocking apart from firewall? Can shed some light on it?

Comment: @LittleBirdy, perhaps a network trace (both client and server) will provide a clue.  If you don't see the packet into the server, it might be a firewall in between.  Run TRACEROUTE to see the hops involved and check each.

Comment: @Dan Guzman Trace completed  '1  < 1 ms    <1 ms     <1 ms Myservername.Domain.com [10.211.55.3]'

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a firewall in between. Try a network trace.

Comment: Hi I tried to trace route. It said completed, can you take a look to above image link and help me point if there is unusual thing? Thanks http://i66.tinypic.com/ih8kr5.jpg

Answer (score 3):

You could install [Netstat](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) or alternatively use the command prompt

```
netstat -abn
```

to see the ports in use.

You could also use [this method from rackspace](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/configuring-ms-sql-server-for-remote-access/) to remotely connect to your server.